# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject

Tags: hibernate, apache-flex, flex3, ejb-3.0, rmi

Currently we are using flex with ejb and i am getting the error. where i am going wrong. can any one help me please. if any code postings are required please let me know .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is most likely a serialization issue. Show both client and server side code please.

Also, checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758006/blazeds-and-arraylist-of-custom-objects

Comment: Hi Dennis, Sorry for late reply.we have sort out the issue and the link which u have given in the reply helped me to improve my knowledge a lot. Thank you

Comment: Then you should answer the solution on your own question and accept it. This will help other users with similar problems to search and narrow down problems themselves.